# Python over SSH - event detect not working

Tags: python-3.x, ssh, raspberry-pi

I am running a Python script on the Pi remotely to control a motor. This is the script -

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setwarnings(False) 

GPIO.setup(10, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN) 

GPIO.setup(11,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(13,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(15,GPIO.OUT)

def button_callback(channel):
    print("Button was pushed!")
    GPIO.output(15,GPIO.LOW)  # assuming this is the connection to the enable pin on your motor controller board
    exit()

# Start motor
GPIO.output(11,GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(13,GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(15,GPIO.HIGH)

GPIO.add_event_detect(10,GPIO.RISING,callback=button_callback) 

message = input("Press enter to quit\n\n") 

GPIO.cleanup()
```

When i run the script from the Pi command line it works fine i.e. the motor stop when the switch is pressed.

When run via the SSH command however from a linux machine the motor doesn't stop when the switch is pressed.

This is the SSH command contained within a shell script -

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh pi@192.168.1.12 "sudo python /home/pi/motor.py"
```

Can anybody give me an idea why the script is not behaving as I would like via SSH and if possible offer a solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem using different code

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
from time import sleep

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setwarnings(False) 


GPIO.setup(10, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN) 

GPIO.setup(11,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(13,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(15,GPIO.OUT)


# Start motor
GPIO.output(11,GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(13,GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(15,GPIO.HIGH)


while True:
    input_state = GPIO.input(10)
    if input_state == True:
        GPIO.output(15,GPIO.LOW)
        time.sleep(30)

message = input("Press enter to quit\n\n") 

GPIO.cleanup()

GPIO.cleanup()
```

I am still curious to know why the previous code didn't work however. Anyway problem solved for now!

Thanks